# Selecting all values with <Null> by using SelectLayerByAttribute_management with input Parameter

Tags: arcpy, select-by-attribute, parameters, null, error-000358

I am trying to select all values with Null by using the SelectLayerByAttribute_management. But the Fieldname in the where-clause is alterable by using the input-parameter.

That is what i tried:

```
if inputValue == "Null":
        ap.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(inputFeature,"NEW_SELECTION", inputFieldname +"IS NULL")
```

Does somebody have an idea what I did wrong?
That's the error message i get:
ExecuteError: ERROR 000358: Invalid expression
Failed to execute (SelectLayerByAttribute).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use three quotes, AddFieldDelimiters and format:

```
sql = """{0} IS NULL""".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(datasource=inputFeature, field=inputFieldname))
ap.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(inputFeature,"NEW_SELECTION", sql)
```

Comment: @Andreas Nice! Please accept my answer with the checkbox

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work:

```
sql = "{0} IS NULL".format(inputFieldname)
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(inputFeature,"NEW_SELECTION", sql)
```

Comment: I dont think it will with shape or fgdb input since they will need double quotes around the field name. Unless `inputFieldname = '"somefield"'`

Comment: @BERA My understanding is that ArcGIS has been very forgiving on field delimiters for the last 3-4 dot releases. I cannot remember the last time that I used them in an SQL expression like this with either a file geodatabase or a shapefile.

Comment: I Think you are correct. I just tried it and it does work without field delimiters.